# Specific number of quarters from date using HiveQL

Tags: hiveql

I am trying to bring a specific number (8) of quarters using a traction date from table. the date format is `YYYYMMDD`

I could write a select using case to display specific quarter depending on current month.

I could find beginning of month using `trunc` function but could not find a logic to bring the last 8 quarters of data

Answer (score 0):

Convert date to Hive format first. 
Then use `DENSE_RANK()` to number rows by quarters (order by year desc and quarter desc) then filter by rnk<=8:

```
select * from 
(
--calculate DENSE_RANK
select s.*, DENSE_RANK() over(order by year(your_date) desc, quarter(your_date) desc) as rnk
from
(
--convert date to YYYY-MM-DD format
  select t.*, from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'yyyyMMdd') your_date 
    from table_name t
--Also restrict your dataset to select only few last years here
--because you do not need to scan all data
--so add WHERE clause here
)s
)s where rnk<=8;
```

See manual on functions here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

You can optimize this query knowing your data and how your table is partitioned, restrict the dataset. Also add `partition by` clause to the `over()` if you need to query last 8 quarters for each key.

Comment: is there a quarter function in hive? i get error right there

Comment: If your Hive version doesn't support it, try this: `ceil(month(your_date) / 3.0)`